# Is there a way to detect dates from emails and save them to the calendar (like on Mac)?

Tags: 22.04, thunderbird, gnome-calendar

I am searching for a way to create a calendar event from an email by detecting the dates in Thunderbird, Evolution or other email client in a way that it's possible on Mac.

Does Ubuntu 22.04 LTS come with that functionality at all?

Comment: That seems like functionality of the email application, not of the operating system. So what you're looking for is an integrated email program/calendar with the capability of detecting dates in emails.

Comment: or look into thunderbird addons, such as https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/tbsync/ (not sure if one exists that detects dates in emails, but look!)